# Set pointer to nil from method or function

Tags: go

Why both these `destroy` functions do not change pointer to nil and how can I create such function?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type position struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func (p *position) destroy() {
    p = nil
}

func destroy(p *position) {
    p = nil
}

func main() {
    p1 := &position{1,1}
    p2 := &position{2,2}
    p1.destroy()
    destroy(p2)

    if p1 == nil {
        fmt.Println("p1 == nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(p1)
    }

    if p2 == nil {
        fmt.Println("p2 == nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(p2)
    }

}
```

Outputs:

```
&{1 1}
&{2 2}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BmZjX1Hw24u

Comment: See related / possible duplicates: [What use case does pointers to pointer (eg **int) have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288751/what-use-case-does-pointers-to-pointer-eg-int-have/45297016#45297016); and [Golang: Can the pointer in a struct pointer method be reassigned to another instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421495/golang-can-the-pointer-in-a-struct-pointer-method-be-reassigned-to-another-inst/35426997#35426997)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a [pointer to pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768344/what-are-pointers-to-pointers-good-for) to change a pointer's value.

Here's your code sample, modified to do this ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2dVKgEaJNEe)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type position struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func destroy(p **position) {
    *p = nil
}

func main() {
    p1 := &position{1, 1}
    destroy(&p1)

    if p1 == nil {
        fmt.Println("p1 == nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(p1)
    }
}
```

---

In your current code

```
func destroy(p *position) {
    p = nil
}
```

Inside `destroy`, `p` is a value the holds the address of a `position` struct. By assigning something to `p` itself, you're simply making it hold the address of some other `position` struct (or `nil`). You're not modifying the original pointer passed in.

This isn't different from a function trying to modify its argument by assigning to it:

```
// This will not actually modify the argument passed in by the caller
func setto2(value int) {
  value = 2
}
```

The go spec says, in the [section about calls and call parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls):

> After they are evaluated, the parameters of the call are passed by
>   value to the function and the called function begins execution. The
>   return parameters of the function are passed by value back to the
>   calling function when the function returns.

Comment: Note that the pass-by-value behavior of go is defined in the spec under [Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)

Comment: @PaSTE: thanks for the suggestion - I have worked this into the answer (feel free to suggest an edit next time!)